# How to represent an array of only certain sizes in Rust

Tags: arrays, generics, rust, const-generics

I would like a data structure that represents an array of values, but which only supports a specific set of sizes and enforces this at compile time. Something like:

```rust
struct MyArray<const N: usize>([u8; N]);
```

But such than `N` can only be a specific set of values, not just any number representable by `usize`. For example, I would like a struct can wrap either a `[u8; 3]`, a `[u8; 6]`, or a `[u8; 9]`, but not a `[u8; N]` for any other `N` besides 3, 6, and 9. I need the enforcement of this constraint to be at compile time, and ideally part of the type system. Is this possible in Rust? Is there a standard pattern or crate for doing this?

Comment: Why not make an "allowed type" `struct` that can only be constructed with specific values? `AllowedSize(usize)` for example. It can then `Into<usize>` trivially. You could have a `TryFrom<usize>` which pops an error, or `From<usize>` which panics on "bad" values.

Comment: @tadman I thought of that, and it would be a usable solution, but what I'm really looking for is for the constraint to be enforced at compile time, not runtime. I feel like implementing these sorts of constraints at compile time is a major strength of Rust's type system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you can also represent the custom array as an enum:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum MyArray<T> {
    Three([T; 3]),
    Six([T; 6]),
    Nine([T; 9]),
}

fn main() {
    let mut array = MyArray::<u8>::Six(Default::default());

    if let MyArray::Three(_) = &array {
        println!("Nope.");
    }

    if let MyArray::Six(array) = &mut array {
        array
            .iter_mut()
            .enumerate()
            .for_each(|(index, element)| *element = index as u8);
    }

    println!("{array:?}");
    println!("Size: {}", std::mem::size_of::<MyArray<u8>>());
}
```

Caveat: This will not be as space efficient as the separate impls, due to the nature of enums (size of largest variant). However, if 9 bytes is the maximum size, I assume that this is not an issue in your case.

Comment: Excellent. This is what I was looking for: a solution that makes it completely impossible to initialize arrays of invalid length. Its too bad this implementation is so wasteful of space though.

Comment: Glad it solves your issue. You should, however also give @Chayim's answer a shot.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by only providing constructors for your desired lengths.

```rust
impl MyArray<3> {
    pub fn new(arr: [u8; 3]) -> Self {
        Self(arr)
    }
}

impl MyArray<6> {
    pub fn new(arr: [u8; 6]) -> Self {
        Self(arr)
    }
}

impl MyArray<9> {
    pub fn new(arr: [u8; 9]) -> Self {
        Self(arr)
    }
}
```

Now outside of the module containing `MyArray`, you will only be able to make `MyArray` values with lengths of 3, 6, or 9.

If you have more numbers, a macro will help.

```rust
macro_rules! impl_my_array {
    ($($n:expr),* $(,)?) => {$(
        impl MyArray<$n> {
            pub fn new(arr: [u8; $n]) -> Self {
                Self(arr)
            }
        }
    )*}
}

impl_my_array! {
    3, 6, 9
}
```

The downside to these is that type inference cannot figure out which `new` to call, so you will need to specify the const generic whenever you construct values.

```rust
//                 V
let ma = MyArray::<3>::new([1, 2, 3]);
```

You may want to give them different names, or provide a higher-level constructor that either picks a specific `new` or returns an error.

---

If you need a large amount of numbers, like to span the entire `usize` range, you'll need to use the `const` trick.

This one allows every `usize` divisible by 3.

```rust
impl<const N: usize> MyArray<N> {
    const LEN_IS_DIVISIBLE_BY_3: () = if N % 3 != 0 {
        panic!("MyArray values must have length divisible by 3");
    };
    pub fn new(arr: [u8; N]) -> Self {
        let _ = Self::LEN_IS_DIVISIBLE_BY_3;
        Self(arr)
    }
}
```

This is used in the bytemuck crate [here](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/src/bytemuck/must.rs.html#9-18) and [here](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/src/bytemuck/must.rs.html#58-61).

Comment: `if !X { panic!("message") }` is usually spelled `assert!(X, "message")` in Rust and [is available here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=38fb737b3b28b658b380b687356b3e53). (only `assert_eq` and similar are not yet available in `const` contexts)

Comment: @ Very good and useful information here, but the constraint enforcement is not iron-clad. Invalid instances of `MyArray` can still be constructed like this: `MyArray([1,2])`. This would initialize a `MyArray<2>` which is not supposed to exist. Is there any way to make invalid instances of `MyArray` impossible to create and enforce this at compile time?

Comment: @RBF06 as long as you put it inside of a module, you can't construct it with that syntax outside of the module.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @drewtato is good, but has two drawbacks: first, code cannot be generic over the size if it wants to create instances, and second, the code duplication (which can be solved with a macro, but that's still not the best thing).

A better solution (IMHO) that is also [used by the standard library for the nightly SIMD module](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/simd/), is to have a trait and implement it only for specific sizes:

```rust
trait SupportedArraySize {}

struct MyArray<const N: usize>([u8; N]);

impl SupportedArraySize for MyArray<3> {}
impl SupportedArraySize for MyArray<6> {}
impl SupportedArraySize for MyArray<9> {}

impl<const N: usize> MyArray<N>
where
    MyArray<N>: SupportedArraySize,
{
    fn new() { /* ... */
    }
}
```